# Upload image with vue JS

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3

Good afternoon, I am relatively new to vue js, your help would be appreciated, in the assets folder there is a folder named "img" and an image named "signature.png", I want to create a form that selects an image from file and copies it to the assets folder, renames in and replaces any image in the folder named "signature.png".

Comment: you can't modify the content of the asset folder from the html. This would be a secutity issue. 

As you are using ionic, I assume you are also using capacitor or cordova and developing a mobile app. 
There are plugins that allows you to store data within the phone memory like this one : 
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem

Comment: Thank you jeremy, this answer seems to have solved my issue